# I can run a local server but not an internet server

Tags: call-of-duty

In Call of Duty 1.1, I am trying to "Start a new server".

If I set "Dedicated" as "LAN", and start the server (after choosing the settings), the green console box is displayed. If I check the status there by typing "status", I can see that my server is running. I can join it by starting the game and going in the "local" servers.

If I do the same by setting "Dedicated" as "Internet" and start the server, the green box appears, as it should. Typing "status", shows the server to be running,  but I can't see it in the "Internet" list of the server (where all the servers of the world are displayed) - I still find it in the "local" list though.

Comment: Wait, what?  You can see it in the Internet list, and still find it in the local list?  Sounds good to me.

Comment: I can see it in the "local" list, not in the "internet" list.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, then.  Chances are pretty good you still see it in local because that's how server searching would work; the test would be a friend somewhere else being able to see your game under Internet, and successfully connecting to it.

Answer (score 1):

In order for people who are not on the same LAN as you to connect to a sever you must do something called [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). This basically maps a port in your external IP address to a specific machine on your network, this way, when someone connects to your IP with that port it knows which computer in the network to connect to.

Comment: I have portforwarded 28960, 28961, 20500 and 20510 (UDP), as is required. My Windows Firewall is also turned off.